# Run Task Scheduling, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-scheduler

I have a Task Scheduling with works if I run the manual command : `php artisan word:weeklyUpdate` , but this must be done automatilcally on a specific date, so I tried to run `* * * * * cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` but I get `Command 'app' not found, did you mean:`

**Kernel.php**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $scheduler = new LkpSchedulerUpdateDate;
    $scheduler = $scheduler->first()->toArray();

    $schedule->command('word:weeklyUpdate')->weeklyOn($scheduler['date'], $scheduler['time']);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
ON `sudo php artisan schedule:run` I get `"No scheduled commands are ready to run."`

Comment: Is the cron in your crontab? _(crontab -e)_

Comment: Yes, I read something in a similar post, so I add it.

Comment: Is your site running on maintenance mode? Schedule don't run then. If you're not in maintenance mode, what happends if you type: `artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`. Also, worth trying `artisan up`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for my case was:

```
 * * * * * php -d register_argc_argv=On /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Its important to note the difference in `cd /some/directory && php artisan` and absolute path to artisan `php /some/directory/artisan` :)